# MongoDB insert not replicating after db.dropDatabase()

Tags: replication, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB (inherited a project using it), so this is especially confusing.

I have a sharded replicaset between 3 ec2 instances. Everything works fine until I drop a database. The database drop replicates just fine - I can verify that - *However*, all subsequent inserts becomes out of sync, and only happen on the particular mongos instance the insert was performed on.

So here's the full process:

1. Connect to mongos at primary:27017
2. use someDatabase;
3. db.dropDatabase();
4. Connect to other 2 mongos and verify DB is dropped.
5. Connect back to primary:27017 and insert a new document in that database
6. Connect to other 2 mongos and realize the insert has not been replicated.

Everything was staying in sync *until* I dropped the database.

Should I not be performing these commands from from the mongos, and instead the primary replica member? I haven't figured out how to clean everything up yet to try and test that.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

More details: I have three ec2 instances that are complete mirrors of each other. Each server has the running app, a single config, a mongos, and three mongod's. I load balance requests between the three of them. I have three replicasets, and each replicaset has a mongod from each server. So a 3x3 array. And each mongos is configured to know about all three config instances.

So. The main issue seems to be that the mongos instances aren't sharing routing information. Each mongos instance only seems to be aware of collections that were inserted while connected to that particular mongos instance. In other words, I'll connect to a mongos instance, insert a document, it ends up on, say, rs0, it replicates fine to the secondaries. Then - I'll connect to a *different* mongos instance, insert a document, it will instead end up on rs1, replicate fine - but I end up in a situation where the mongos instances are only aware of inserts that happened through themselves. So, in essence, each app server ends up with a seeing a different set of data - which isn't what I want.

Is this expected behavior? I'm thinking the dropDatabase issue is actually just a red herring?

Comment: I've removed my original answer because it is going to take several more iterations to get the right information to diagnose the issue. Based on what you have described, I would need to see: the mongos config, the mongos logs, the replica set config on each shard, the output of `sh.status()` from each mongos, the logs from the primary in each replica set and the logs from the config servers. Basically this is a troubleshooting question that is not well suited to the DBA format - you might have more luck on the mongodb-user google group

Comment: I appreciate your help none-the-less!

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using? If you are dropping & reusing a sharded database, it is likely you are encountering [SERVER-17397: Dropping a Database or Collection in a Sharded Cluster may not fully succeed](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17397). There are some workarounds noted in the Jira issue to ensure database metadata is completely removed.